# Oracle: Non key-preserved table should be

Tags: oracle, join, update

I'm getting "ORA-01779: cannot modify a column which maps to a non key-preserved table" when I try to update a join.  I've searched around the site and found a lot of advice on what key-preserved means and why it is necessary... but as near as I can tell I'm complying with that advice, and still getting the error.

I have two tables:

```
PG_LABLOCATION has, among other things, the columns:
"LABLOCID" NUMBER,
"DNSNAME" VARCHAR2(200 BYTE)

LABLOCID is the primary key, DNSNAME has a unique constraint

PG_MACHINE has, among other things, the columns:
"MACHINEID" NUMBER, 
"LABLOCID" NUMBER, 
"IN_USE" NUMBER(1,0) DEFAULT 0, 
"UPDATE_TIME" TIMESTAMP (6) DEFAULT '01-JAN-1970'

MACHINEID is a primary key
LABLOCID is a foreign key into LABLOCID in PG_LABLOCATION (its primary key)
```

The update I'm running is:

```
update 
  (select mac.in_use, mac.update_time
     from pg_machine mac 
     inner join pg_lablocation loc
       on mac.lablocid = loc.lablocid
     where loc.dnsname = 'value'
       and '02-JAN-2013' > mac.update_time
  )
set in_use = 1 - MOD( 101, 2 ), update_time = '02-JAN-2013';
```

I'm only updating values in one table (PG_MACHINE) and the join column in the other table is the primary key, which should make it key-preserved by my reading.  I'm concerned that the where clause is causing the problem, but I tried removing the filter on mac.update_time and got the same error, and loc.dnsname has a unique constraint.

What's even odder is that we have, like many folks, a dev and a prod environment.  We did a complete schema and data migration from prod to dev.  I've looked them both over and they have identical indexes and constraints.  The query works in dev, but generates the above error in prod.

So two questions:

1) Can you see what's wrong with my query?
2) Can you suggest what might be different between my dev and prod environment (e.g. server settings) that could cause this error in one but not the other?

Comment: No unique index on PG_MACHINE.LABLOCID ?

Comment: Yes, there is.  Mea culpa; I was trying to pare down the description of the problem to forum length, and cut too deep.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can update a join in Oracle if the [following conditions are met](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/21/admin/managing-views-sequences-and-synonyms.html#GUID-C37E704C-AF40-42DA-85ED-372A62A74E58):

1. Only one base table is updated
2. All other tables are [key-preserved](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/21/admin/managing-views-sequences-and-synonyms.html#GUID-A661DF5B-A5CE-4569-B5F1-AE8D407E6D30): each of them must have **at most** one row for each row of the base table.

(additional [restrictions on updating views](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/21/sqlrf/CREATE-VIEW.html#GUID-61D2D2B4-DACC-4C7C-89EB-7E50D9594D30__CEGCADFA) apply)

In your example you update table `PG_MACHINE` only. Oracle has to make sure that for a single row of this table, only one row of the other can be found. This seems to be the case since you have a PK on `PG_LABLOCATION.LABLOCID`. Therefore you should be able to update the join. See for example this [SQLFiddle with a similar setup](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/cba28/1).

In your case you should either:

- make sure that the primary key is enabled, validated, [not deferrable](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/c32e8/1) (interestingly, a deferrable constraint prevents Oracle from updating the join!)
- use [`MERGE`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/21/sqlrf/MERGE.html) if `PG_LABLOCATION.LABLOCID` is unique for the relevant query. `MERGE` is less strict than update with joins and will only return an error if there is *actually* a duplicate in the result set (whereas `UPDATE` will fail if there is the *possibility* of a duplicate).
- review your query, since you don't need values from the parent table in the `SELECT` clause, you could rewrite it as a semi-join (that guarantees that no duplicate will be generated):

  ```
    UPDATE (SELECT mac.in_use, mac.update_time
              FROM pg_machine mac
             WHERE mac.lablocid IN (SELECT loc.lablocid 
                                      FROM pg_lablocation loc 
                                     WHERE loc.dnsname = 'value')
               AND to_date('02-JAN-2013') > mac.update_time)
       SET in_use = 1 - MOD(101, 2), 
           update_time = to_date('02-JAN-2013');
  ```

  This could be rewritten as:

  ```
    UPDATE pg_machine mac
       SET in_use = 1 - MOD(101, 2), 
           update_time = to_date('02-JAN-2013')
     WHERE mac.lablocid IN (SELECT loc.lablocid 
                              FROM pg_lablocation loc 
                             WHERE loc.dnsname = 'value')
       AND to_date('02-JAN-2013') > mac.update_time;
  ```

In this case I would go with the third option: in general **you can't update the parent in a parent-child join**.

Comment: Thanks for the advice!

Unfortunately, I've led you astray; PG_MACHINE.LABLOCID does have a unique constraint on it, which I failed to catch and mention when writing it up.  But I tried your semi-join rewrite anyways - I'd shied away from that structure thinking it was a correlated subquery, but of course it isn't - and it worked a treat.  I'd still dearly love to know why it runs differently in our dev environment than it does in prod, and why the unique constraint doesn't make the table key-preserved, but I'll certainly settle for "It works now" and be happy.

Comment: (The varchar to date conversion is just a result of me stripping the problem down to its essence for the forum; the real case lives in a trigger and replaces 101, 'value', and the date in both places with variables of the appropriate type.  But I do appreciate the advice all the same.)  (Also, apologies for not upvoting your response; apparently I'm not reputable enough.)

Comment: @rob I got confused with parent-child. Your update should succeed, see this [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/cba28/1) example, you don't even need a unique constraint on `PG_MACHINE.LABLOCID` !! The error message could come from a *deferrable* constraint in one environment, see this other [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/46eac/1). About the date conversion, you can use [this notation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/sql_elements003.htm#SQLRF51062) for literal dates =)

Comment: None of the links in @VincentMalgrat's answers or comments are working

Comment: @Anuswadh: I fixed the links to point to the most recent version of the documentation

Comment: @Vincent Malgrat
 Thank you